# Given an arbitrary function f, how would you go about writing a function g that replicates f's implementation?

Tags: algorithms

You are given an arbitrary function `f`. You may invoke it with arbitrary parameters and read the return values, as well as record any exceptions it raises, but you may not read its implementation.

How would you go about writing a function `g` that replicates `f`'s implementation?

Note that by "function" I do not mean to restrict `f` to being a mathematical function; it can operate on any data type, not just numbers. "Program" may be a better word for it. However, if it makes thinking about the problem easier, it can helpful to first think in terms of numbers only, as a start.

Note also that I don't think certainty/proof of correctness is possible here; only error correction is.

---

Edit for clarification (posted after some of the answers): `g` may not invoke `f` in its implementation.

Comment: This sounds very much like a homework question. What have you attempted so far? What is your goal?

Comment: Without any additional information (is f assumed to be pure, and can it have side effects? Is anything known about the requirements context?), the answer is "it makes no sense even to try it, this is next to impossible, except for extremely simple cases of f". And if this is an interview or homework question: we don't answer such things here, sorry.

Comment: do you know anything about the domain of f?

Comment: This is not a homework question. We have good explanations suggesting that humans copy memes this way. See https://soundcloud.com/dchacke/artificial-creativity-06-function-replication

Comment: Are you saying you've posted a meme here?

Comment: @jk. No. ------

Comment: @DocBrown You may guess that f is pure, and that it has no side effects; but you may be mistaken about it.

Answer (score 4):

```
function g(args) {
  return f(args);
}
```

If `f` is off in some other language, then you get to do a foreign function call. If it is some exe, then you exec it (though good luck serializing the i/o). If it is some service, just call the service (though good luck serializing the i/o). If it is some hidden library, then your function gets to disassemble it and then run the disassembled instructions. If it is some arcane machine language, then you get to emulate the machine. If it is some black box silicon, then `g` gets to instruct some robot and machine vision to reverse engineer the chip or flip some bits to run the chip directly.

But it all boils down to the only way `g` can reproduce `f` is to execute `f` or some copy of it. Trialing inputs will get you some approximation, but you're never *sure* you've replicated it with arbitrary inputs. And that's assuming it's a pure function. If the function returns 0 except for leap seconds when I am eating a cheeseburger, good luck replicating that experimentally.

Comment: And even this falls apart if your function can introspect the call stack.

Comment: Thanks, but this is cheating. I'm editing my question to make that clear.

Comment: @weltschmerz - then you literally cannot do this. It's analogous to the halting problem.

Comment: Please expand. How is it analogous?

Comment: @weltschmerz - you're trying to determine if a specific output will occur given some arbitrary input. The halting problem is determining if a specific output (halting) will occur given some arbitrary input. I am not a great computer scientist so can't provide a handy proof.

Comment: According to my very rough understanding, the halting problem applied to this means we can't find *all* the right input/output pairs - though please let me know if that's not what you mean. If it is what you mean, that's not what I am after. I am after conjecturing solutions and trying them out to find mistakes; not making sure they're correct. Clearly this can be done: if `f() = 1` and I conjecture `g() = 1`, I have accidentally found the correct implementation. Can I prove it? No. Does it matter? No. My guess is a genetic algorithm would help with this.

Comment: @weltschmerz - but you never, ever know that you have found a correct implementation since you can’t run your black box. You don’t ever _know_ that `f` returns 1 for all inputs. You say that doesn’t matter, but I assure you, it very much does for any practical application.

Comment: What you're after is certain knowledge, which is not attainable. You don't *know* (in your sense of the word) of any function you write that it will always return what you think it returns. And yet you still use those functions you write because you tentatively accept them as solutions to problems, no?

Comment: @weltschmerz - what? Pretty much every function I write has well defined behavior. Other people can read the code and come to the same answer for "if you give this function this input, what does it output?". If you want to claim that processor malfunction means I can't be certain about the behavior... at that point you're into fractions of zillions territory. Your question is _not that_. Your question is about a black box that could literally do anything. There is no well defined behavior there. There is no way you can approximate something that has infinite variability.

Comment: @weltschmerz: Editing a question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers is considered extremely rude on Stack Exchange. Please do not do this. It makes the answerer look like an idiot because it looks like he is answering the wrong question, and will generally lead to people downvoting the answer as "not helpful".

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me a lot of *programming by example*. Sumit Gulwani from Microsoft has some [very interesting talks](https://databricks.com/session/programming-by-examples) with papers cited. Basically, the possible language is simplified a lot, so the number of possibilities are limited. In his talk it is limited to relatively basic data transformations of the sort you do in typical data cleaning.

Next, possible programs are generated, then ranked. There is also a stage that looks for potential problem areas, which the user is prompted to fix by providing more clarifying examples.

Since you have a function to duplicate, rather than a human providing examples, you could start with the kind of random inputs generated by property-based testing libraries like [QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck).

Indeed, it is probably impossible to generate a function which will be 100% accurate in all cases.  For example, you could have a function like `if (in == 3 trillion) 0 else 1`, but for certain classes of problems where close is good enough, it is certainly possible to make something usable.

Comment: https://microsoft.github.io/prose/ is the SDK you can use to make use of Sumit Gulwani et al's work.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was talking about. My guess is that a program that can do this not only for DSLs, but for general purpose languages, comes pretty close to human level intelligence.